# CSV var as expression is empty, shown as {}

Tags: powershell, csv

I got a small issue. I have a CSV with some names. I needed to get the email addresses of those users, so I created a small script that will find users with that firstname and lastname in AD.

After that, I wanted to export it to a new CSV file, but keep the phone-numbers from the first CSV file so its also available in the new CSV export.

That last part don't seem to work. In the output that expression is shown as {}.

Can someone help me?

```
$csv = import-csv -path C:\users\da6\desktop\UsersZonderEmail.csv
$output = @()
foreach ($i in $csv) {
  
  $givenname = $i.Voornaam
  $lastname = $i.Achternaam
  $number = $i.IpPhone
  $output += try {Get-ADUser -Filter {givenname -eq $givenname -and surname -eq $lastname} | select Name, UserPrincipalName, @{ name="ipphone"; expression=$number}} catch {}
}
```

Comment: Does your input CSV file indeed have a column header `'IpPhone` ? You say you also want the email addresses, but make no effort to ask for that property.. Can you show us the first 3 or 4 lines of the input CSV as displayed in notepad?

Comment: Common mistake from my part, our UPN is identical to the emailaddress, its a habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is wrong with your code is that you forgot the opening bracket `{` in the `expression` oart of the calculated property.

Also note that `-Filter` should be a **string**, not a scriptblock.

Lastly, adding to an array with `+=` is a bad habit, as the **entire** array needs to be rebuilt in memory on every addition.

Better let PowerShell collect the values from the loop:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\users\da6\desktop\UsersZonderEmail.csv'
$output = foreach ($item in $csv) {
  Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($item.Voornaam)' -and Surname -eq '$($item.Achternaam)'" -Properties EmailAddress | 
  Select-Object Name, UserPrincipalName, @{ Name="ipphone"; Expression = {$item.IpPhone}}, EmailAddress
}
# output to new CSV file
$output | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\users\da6\desktop\UsersMetEmail.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thank you! Didn't know that we should use string for filter, thanks!